# How to scale an entire webpage down to ipad or phone size

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm fairly new to responsive CSS design, and I just can't get a very simple thing working.
I have a DIV that is about 1200px wide. I want this div to display scaled down to the maximum screen size when viewed on an iPad or smartphone.

For example, when you visit a non-responsive website on a smartphone, you will see the entire website scaled down to a tiny size on the phone screen. This is actually non-responsive, but somehow I can't reproduce that scaling-down effect:

My divs:

```
<div id="app">
    <div id="screen">This is my screen</div>
</div>
```

My css:

```
html,body {
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}
#app {
  width:1200px;
  height:800px;
  background-color:#CCCCCC;
  overflow:auto;
}
#screen {
  width:800px;
  height:400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color:#ABABAB;
}

/* this is only for large screens: scale the background up to fill the entire screen */
@media only screen and (min-width : 1200px) {
  #app {
      width:100%;
      height:100%;
      background-color:#999999;
  }
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Htp47/) here. How do I display these divs scaled down on small screens?

Comment: please, don't make the poor mobile user download a 1200px x 800px image, if there is any

Comment: I know this is far from ideal, but all I really need is to scale the website down just a little bit, so that it fits nicely on an iPad screen. 1200 px is only a little bigger than the iPad's 1024px.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1"/>
```

This will give you the scaling you're looking for.

Comment: That doesn't seem to do anything. I uploaded a file to my testserver: http://www.nightoferror.nl/test/ If I open it on an iPad, the main div remains too large for the screen.

Comment: Try adding maximum-scale=1 to the meta, this will stop users zooming, but it might be automatically zooming, so it appears to not fit correctly.

Comment: Thanks, it's almost working! The only problem now is that rotating the device does not correctly scale the website down and back up again.

Comment: It might assume that it's been scaled by the user so try adding user-scalable=no. If that fails then you'll need to edit your css media queries and add (orientation:landscape) and (orientation:portrait) min-widths.